# Correlate two floats using c#

Tags: c#, math

I know im an idiot and I am sure this is simple math. But I cannot seem to wrap my head around it here is my situation

When `X = 3`, I need `Y = 0`, and when `X = 0` I need `y = 1`;.
I am trying to fill a progress bar based upon how low `X` is.

The value to fill the progress bar (`Y`) must be between `0` and `1`.

Math?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: If you can't solve this problem then there is a simpler problem that you can solve. How would you write "when x = 3 I need y to be 0 and when x is 0 I need y to be 3"?

Answer (score 3):

```
// "Single" is just like "float"
Single y = (3.0f - x) / 3.0f;
```

So that

```
x=3 -> y=0.00
x=2 -> y=0.33
x=1 -> y=0.66
x=0 -> y=1.00
```

Alternatively:

```
// different points of view are better
Single y = -(x - 3.0f) / 3.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know best from my high school:

y = a*x + b
You must solve equations:
0 = a*3 + b and
1 = a*0 + b

a = -b/3; b =1

So your equation is: y=-1/3*x+1

```
private float GetProgressValue(float x)
{
    return x/-3f + 1f;
}
```